# How To Source Bootstrap Popover Template From File?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [angularjs ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), and I have my popover template all set up and working. Here is what I have.

directive.html

```
...
    popover-title="Title"
    popover-template="'popover.template.html'"
...
```

A bit lower in the same directive I have the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover.template.html">
          <label>Popup Title:</label>
          <span>Popup content</span>

</script>
```

Now I will need this popover for a few elements, so how can I put it in an actual popover.template.html file in my source tree I just made in the same directory in the simplest way (least lines of code) possible?

Comment: If angular doesn't find that script template it will make ajax request to path supplied

Comment: Would I still need the script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was this:

- leave the script tags needed for inline tags behind
- give the template parameter the full path
- create a new file in the desired place, no header needed inside
- then add to the element you want popover to work on this:

popover-template="'app/templates/popover.template.html'"

No need for templateCache or any other tricks, the site only sends a single request, even with multiple elements using the same template. It loads on first request.

Comment: Well, I was doing just what you say but didn't work. Than I realized that popover-template "consumes" a variable. So here I would like to emphasize that you should surround the template url with single quotes inside of html double-quotes :-)

Comment: That is how it appears in my code so it does work. It is actually a triple quote, double in the outside and single in the inside. Maybe not all of them are needed though.